# Getting JSON data from jQuery AJAX call on a PHP page 

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I would like to send data using the jQuery Ajax API:

```
var myData = {"param1" : $('#txtParam1').val(), "param2" : $('#txtParam2').val()};

$.ajax({
    url: 'DataService.php?action=SomeAction',
    type: 'POST',
    data: myData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(result) {
    alert(result.Result);}
});
```

When I tried to retrieve this data with PHP using

```
    $param1 = $_REQUEST['param1'];
```

`$param1` is showing `null` and `print_r($_REQUEST)` is only showing action = SomeAction ..

How do I retrieve the posted data on a PHP page?

Comment: Here is Posted Data (viewed using FireBug Console)
param1=somevalue1&param2=somevalue2

Comment: about REQUEST... http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2008/09/request-security-problem.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$params = json_decode( $_POST['param1']);
```

And then check what you have got:

```
var_export( $params);
```

Or you can use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach( $params as $param)
{
    echo $param . '<br />';
}
```

You are using POST, method, dont use REQUEST because it is also less secure.

Comment: @Nav Ali: try removing the  dataType: 'json' line from your code and then see.

Comment: can get the data when I removed content-type

Answer (score 9):

since you're sending the ajax as "contentType: 'application/json'", you need to fetch the request body with [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) like so:

```
$request = file_get_contents("php://input"); // gets the raw data
$params = json_decode($request,true); // true for return as array
print_r($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$param1 = $_POST['param1'];
```